# JSON: Use Pexels API key

Tags: javascript, json, access-token

I'm starting to learn JSON, and on my entire journey I haven't come across API keys when working with APIs. I'm trying to work the pexels API, found here https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation/?language=javascript. I was given an API key, how do I use it in JSON. I know this is a ridiculous question, but I haven't been able to find out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go through the documentation they have given how to use your API_KEY.

you can check docs [here](https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation/?#authorization).

You have to pass `API_KEY` in request `header` as `Authorization`.

```
curl -H "Authorization: YOUR_API_KEY" \
  "https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=people"
```

JS

```js
fetch("https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=people", {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: where do I do that

Comment: this is Curl command so you run from your terminal, for javascript you can use `fetch` and call this

Comment: What do I after that

Comment: $.getJSON(URL, function (data) { what do I put for URL

Comment: Do whatever you want to do with returned JSON, your question was how to pass `API_KEY` so I answered for that. URL is like what I have used in my example......If answer has solved your initial question then accept it and create new question for other issue.

Answer (score 1):

First I'll recommend you create an env file in the root of your project called .env.local

Afterwards add the Key to this env file

```
YOUR_API_KEY = '1232123123123123123'  <== your key insted of these random numbers
```

then you safely use your key to make fetch calls, then reach for some pexels endopint like this

```
export const getDataFromApi = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
  ENDPOINT_URL,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: API_KEY,
    },
  }
);
  const responseJson = await res.json();
  return responseJson.photos;
};
```